# Mysql print repeated characters based on length

Tags: mysql, sql, string

What I want to do is basically print "xxxx" for "asda"
or "xxxxxx" for "forget". The number of characters should be same.

what I have tried in sql

Suppose I run

```
select length("adsa")
```

I get `4`

and when I run this :

```
select repeat('x',  4);
```

I get `xxxx`

Now when I try doing this :

```
select repeat('x',  select length("adsa"));
```

It throws error. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
select repeat('x',  (select length("adsa")));
```

just wrap your last select in brackets.

If you are working against a table you can leave out the extra brackets:

```
select repeat('x',  length(my_col))
from my_table
```

Comment: ohh I missed the parenthesis , thanks for your help my friend

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `select` at all in the second argument:

```
select repeat('x', length('adsa'));
```

I would also recommend using single quotes for all string constants.